# Klatura API: How do I retrieve a list of all media entries, not just those that have content?

Tags: kaltura

I'm using the Kaltura v3 API, uploading a video to the server.  I'd like to be able to query the API and ask if I have a MediaEntry added, but with no media (or upload token) associated with it.  It seems like media:list would be the correct action, but it doesn't return any results that don't have media already associated.

Is there a parameter I can send to media:list to get these entries? Or another API call I should be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to list all media entries that don't have video associated, use the following. Example is in PHP, but will be the same in every language if you use a client library -

```
$filter = new KalturaMediaEntryFilter();
$filter->statusEqual = KalturaEntryStatus::NO_CONTENT;
$result = $client->media->listAction($filter);
```

Comment: If anyone is having to work without a generated API, NO_CONTENT is the string "7".

Comment: Jeff - KalturaEntryStatus::NO_CONTENT is an enum value of 7. Not a string: http://www.kaltura.com/api_v3/testmeDoc/?object=KalturaEntryStatus